# Given n-degree polynomial and one point, find f(1)

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given $$f(n)={a_n}x^n+{a_{n-1}}x^{n-1}+...+{a_1}x^1+{a_0}x^0$$
$$f(7)=51983$$
Where n is natural, and $a_n, a_{n-1}, ... a_0$ are non-negative integers smaller than or equal to 6.

Find $f(1)$

---

Because $7^5<51983, 7^6>31983$,

$a_n, a_{n-1}, ..., a_6=0$

Therefore, we are left with 6 coefficients to consider.

$$a^5\times7^5+a^4\times7^4+a^3\times7^3+a^2\times7^2+a^1\times7^1+a^0\times1$$

However, trying all different values from 0 to 6 of 6 varuables is still a lot of work. Any shortcuts from here?

Edit: Reducing mod $7^1$, $7^2$, ... will find $a_1$ to $a_6$, then summing all the coefficients up gives us $f(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $f(7) = 51983$ and $a_i \in \{0,1,...,6\}$ means that $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ are digits in expansion of $51938$ with respect to base $7$. In order to find $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ you need to find this expansion. There exists a standard algorithm for that. Begin by noting that
$$a_0 = 51983\,\mathrm{mod}\,7$$

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily solved by simple calculation.

$51983\div7=7426\cdots1$, so $a_0=1$.

$7426\div7=1060\cdots6$, so $a_1=6$.

$1060\div7=151\cdots3$, so $a_2=3$.

$151\div7=21\cdots4$, so $a_3=4$.

$21\div7=3\cdots0$, so $a_4=0, a_5=3$.

And as you said, $f(7)<7^6$, so $n\ge6\Rightarrow a_n=0$.